# Access document when you don't know the document name

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am learning flutter and creating my first mobile app. I have learned a lot from many of you during this process.

I have a new question. My app has multiple documents in a certain collection in Firestore. I want to access the data from one document but I don't know the document name. How can I access a document in flutter when I don't know the document name?

Comment: If you don't know the ID, you will have to perform a query using something you know about the contents of its fields.  I suggest reviewing the documentation.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the document name to access the document, but the document has to have a unique field so you can filter the collection out and access that document.

```
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance
final query = firestore.collection('myCollection').where('uniqueField', isEqualTo: uniqueValue);
final docs = (await  query.get()).docs; 
final document = docs.first.data();
```

Please note, the last line of code assumes that you're sure there's only one document. If that's not the case, you've to check the length of the docs and do extra checking after that to filter the docs out and find your document.

Also, if you end up filtering documents on the flutter side and you're not sure about how many documents will be returned, it'll be a good idea to limit the query by adding additional `where` filters and using `limit` method at the end of the query.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using a DocumentSnapshot to pull the data and am getting the following error: "A value of type 'Query' can not be assigned to a variable of type 'DocumentSnapshot'.

Comment: Here is a code snippet: getCurrentAgentProfile() async {
    final DocumentSnapshot currentAgent =
    await agentsRef.where('agentId', isEqualTo: globals.currentUid.get());

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was able to get it to work.

Comment: @LostTexan I'm glad I was of help. Don't forget to mark the answer as answered please if that solved your problem and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You don't query off of DocumentReferences (one document); you query off of CollectionReferences (sets of documents).  A DocumentSnapshot is just a single document.  I don't use flutter (yet; give me a week or two), so I can't help you with the code syntax.

Comment: If you *have* the DocumentSnapshot (which the earlier comment implies), that *is* the reference to the document (or, more accurately, one of it's *properties*is the reference to the document)